# ID CC2015 username

Tags: authentication, adobe-indesign

Is it a way to catch InDesign CC username (the one used for log on) by script?
Unfortunatelly cant test it on  my side (older version).

I mean username shown in menu "Help"

Thx in advance

PS. Nothing sinful. I just want to limit a script usage basing on list of registered users. Dont think it categorizes as "bad question"...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it sounds like you are trying to get Adobe ID. This is not supported by Indesign DOM, AppleScript or ExtendScript.

Comment: There is an app property: app.userAdobeId but it returns 'undefined' if user is logged out. Since to log in is an option only - basing on this property is useless :(

Comment: Why don't you just get a Windows/Mac username of the current user?

Comment: $.getenv("USERNAME"); and $.getenv("USER");

Comment: since ID CC is a cloud app - make it based on app login looks better.

Comment: However - thanks for your time. I am releasing this idea for now, so lets close it :)